# division during pointer subtraction in C

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Consider below code snippet :

```
int *p;
/* Lets say p points to address 100 
   and sizeof(int) is 4 bytes. */
int *q = p+1;
unsigned long r = q-p;
/* r results in 1, hence for r = q-p 
   something is happening similar to r=(104-100)/4 */
```

Is there a real division by sizeof(datatype) going on during runtime when two pointers of same type are subtracted, or there is some other mechanism through which pointer subtraction works.

Comment: There's no pointer arithmetic here.

Comment: @JGroven I have updated the snippet.

Comment: More likely a shift than a division as the size of integer types is usually a power of 2. This is different from the converse: computing an address from an array index, where a processor might have an instruction that inherently does the multiply. But as @Yunnosch says that is an implementation detail.

Comment: You set `q = p + 1`. Why are you surprised that `q - p` is `1`, since that's what you added?

Comment: @Yunnosch What if OP had done: `int arr[2]; int *p = &arr[0]; int *q = p + 1; unsigned long r = q - p;` I believe OP is more interested why the value of `r` is 1 and not 4 [and if a division by 4 is done to get 1--which can be optimized to a shift].

Comment: @Barmar: The question is about the underlying implementation, not the result. The OP expresses no surprise at the result, so it is wrong to infer it.

Comment: The specific method will be implementation-dependent, although it's arithmetically equivalent to division.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states the following regarding pointer subtraction (section 6.5.6p9):

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object, or  one  past  the  last  element  of  the  array 
>   object;  **the  result  is  the  difference  of  the subscripts  of  the
>   two array  elements**.  The  size  of  the  result  is 
>   implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is
>   ptrdiff_t defined in the  header. If  the  result  is  not 
>   representable  in  an  object  of  that  type,  the  behavior  is 
>   undefined.  In other words, if the expressions P and Q point to,
>   respectively, the i
>   -th and j
>   -th elements of an array object, the expression (P)-(Q) has the value i−j provided the value fits in an object of type ptrdiff_t . Moreover,
>   if the  expression P points either to an element of an array object or
>   one past the last element of an array object, and the expression Q
>   points to the last element of the same array object, the expression
>   ((Q)+1)-(P) has the same value  as ((Q)-(P))+1 and  as
>   -((P)-((Q)+1)) ,  and  has  the  value  zero  if  the expression P points  one  past  the  last  element  of  the  array  object,  even 
>   though  the expression (Q)+1 does not point to an element of the array
>   object. <sup>106)</sup>

Footnote 106 states:

> **Another way to approach pointer arithmetic is first to convert the
>   pointer(s) to character pointer(s)**: In this scheme the integer
>   expression added to or subtracted from the converted pointer is first
>   multiplied by  the  size  of  the  object  originally  pointed  to, 
>   and  the  resulting  pointer  is  converted  back  to  the original 
>   type.  **For pointer  subtraction,  the  result  of  the  difference 
>   between  the  character  pointers  is similarly divided by the size of
>   the object originally pointed to.** When  viewed  in  this  way, an
>   implementation  need  only  provide  one  extra  byte  (which  may 
>   overlap another object in the program) just after the end of the
>   object in order to satisfy the "one past the last element"
>   requirements.

So the footnote states that pointer subtraction *may* be implemented by subtracting the raw pointer values and dividing by the size of the pointed-to object.  It doesn't have to be implemented this way, however.

Note also that the standard requires that pointer subtraction is performed between pointers pointing to elements of the same array object (or one element past the end).  If they don't then the behavior is undefined.  In practice, if you're working on a system with a flat memory model you'll probably still get the "expected" values but you can't depend on that.

Answer (score 1):

See @dbush answer for the explanation on how pointer substraction works.

If, instead, you are programming something low-level, say a kernel, driver, debugger or similar and you need to have actual subtraction of addresses, cast the pointers to `char *`:

```
(char *)q - (char *)p
```

The result will be of `ptrdiff_t` type, an implementation defined signed integer.

Of course, this is not defined/portable C, but will work on most architectures/environments.